# Need assistance getting around runtime error of Hackerrank problem

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out why my for loop at the very end is producing a runtime error. It seems all fine to me and I'm at a loss of figuring a way around it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
            arr[i] = arrItem;
        }

        scanner.close();
        for(int i = n; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: yes please post the relevant error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottom-most for loop starts from n when it should start from n-1

```
    for(int i = n; i >= 0; --i) // should be for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
```

which is possibly one of the errors in your code.

Comment: @NiVeR , isn't the --i in the for loop executed after the body in the loop is executed? In that case --i or i-- makes no difference. Check here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html. It says that "The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value."

Comment: yea i just tried that and it solved the runtime error lol, thanks! im trying to figure out why thats the case